# save multiple pdf pages with different sizes in Shiny R

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, pdf-generation

Im developing a shiny app with several features. I added a button to download a single pdf file that contains many plots. I want to save those plots in individual pages but I want to choose the size of each pdf page. Is that possible?

This is he code that  have so far:

```
output$exportall<-downloadHandler(
filename="Allplots.pdf",
content=function(file){
  withProgress(message = 'Exporting', min=0,max=1, { 
    pdf(file,width=8,height=11)
    print(plot1())
    print(histogram())
    print(plots2())
    print(marrangeGrob(woodsbytimepoint(), nrow=2, ncol=1))
    print(digestion())
    print(map())
    print(marrangeGrob(allplots(), nrow=4, ncol=2, top=NULL))
    
  dev.off()
  })
 }
)
```

The code works fine and exports all the plots that I want. However, all pages in the pdf file are 8x11. Is there a way to speciffy the size of each page? for example I want the first plot to be 7x7 and all other 8x11.

Any ideas?

Comment: Options: (1) use an r-markdown document, where you can go through the possible yet admittedly-laborious process of changing paper-size for each page; or (2) create individual PDFs sized as desired, and use a tool to concatenate PDF files, such as `qpdf::pdf_combine` (R package/function) or `pdftk` (not R, this is an external program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest is to create separate PDFs (sized appropriately) and combine them with `qpdf::pdf_combine`.

```r
file <- "file.pdf"
pdf(paste0(file, ".8x11"), width=8, height=11)
plot(disp ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point()
print(gg)
dev.off()
pdf(paste0(file, ".7x7"), width=7, height=7)
print(gg) # or anything else
dev.off()
qpdf::pdf_combine(paste0(file, c(".8x11", ".7x7")), file)
file.remove(paste0(file, c(".8x11", ".7x7")))
```

The resulting `file.pdf` pages:

[image]

If your sizes are not always in order (e.g., 8x11, 7x7, 8x11), you can either:

- create three PDF files (would need an adjusted file name convention) and concatenate in order, or
- create two PDF files (by dimensions), then also use `qpdf::pdf_subset` ... though since this creates new PDF files that you would then need to include in `pdf_combine`, it hardly seems the most efficient method.

I cannot test this, but I think this means your code should be

```r
output$exportall<-downloadHandler(
filename="Allplots.pdf",
content=function(file){
  withProgress(message = 'Exporting', min=0,max=1, { 
    pdf(paste0(file, ".7x7"), width=7, height=7)
    print(plot1())
    dev.off()
    pdf(paste0(file, ".8x11"), width=8, height=11)
    print(histogram())
    print(plots2())
    print(marrangeGrob(woodsbytimepoint(), nrow=2, ncol=1))
    print(digestion())
    print(map())
    print(marrangeGrob(allplots(), nrow=4, ncol=2, top=NULL))
    dev.off()
    qpdf::pdf_combine(paste0(file, c(".7x7", ".8x11")), output=file)
  })
 }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I like the approach but I'm having trouble making it work since its a shiny app and not plain R. and the code its in a downloadHandler.
Will keep trying and post an update later

Comment: The premise has nothing to do with shiny, but I edited in what might work for you. If it doesn't work, please edit your OP and add in the code attempted and all warnings/errors you get. @JuanPabloRincon

Comment: It worked perfectly! The only issue is that there is a blank page between the two merged documents, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Are all of the functions you use making ggolot2 gross, or are any of the base graphics?

Comment: all of them are ggplot()

Comment: I can't reproduce the blank page

Comment: seems to be a know issue https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR/issues/90
https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/24

Comment: If you don't mind using an external tool, the [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) utility allows for arbitrary page selection when combining PDFs. For instance, on the shell (not in R): `pdftk A=file.pdf.7x7 B=file.pdf.8x11 A B2-end output file.pdf` might work for you. (Or remove whichever page is problematic, I'm assuming the first page of the 8x11 file.)